# Iterating 2D array in Swift

Tags: array, swift, iteration

I have a situation where I needed to convert `NSNumber` 2D array to `Float` 2D array, so I did it like this:

```
var numArr:[[NSNumber]]()
//fill values
let floatArr = numArr.map { $0.map { $0.floatValue} }
```

It's working fine, no issues!

But I wondering if there's any better way to handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is fine, an equivalent method in **Swift 3** would be

```
let floatArr = numArr.map { $0.map { Float($0) } }
```

You get the same result with less code by using the
bridging cast from `NSNumber` to `Float`, which works for (nested)
arrays as well:

```
if let floatArr = numArr as [[Float]] { ... }
```

Actually I don't know of any case (in Swift 3) where this cast can fail.

Things change a bit in **Swift 4,** as a consequence of
[SE 0170 - NSNumber bridging and Numeric types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0170-nsnumber_bridge.md). Your code still works fine, and is equivalent 
to

```
let floatArr = numArr.map { $0.map { Float(truncating: $0) } }
```

The truncating initializers where introduced because not every
`Number` can be converted to a scalar value without loosing information,
there are also failable `init?(exactly:)` initializers.

Now the bridged cast *can* fail

- for numbers which are not exactly representable as a `Float`,
  such as `Double(1.1)`,
- for numbers which exceed the range of `Float`.

(The first case is currently discussed at https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20170612/037499.html and may change in the future.)

Example:

```
let numArr = [
    [ NSNumber(value: 1.1), NSNumber(value: 2.0) ],
    [ NSNumber(value: Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude) ],
]

if let floatArr = numArr as? [[Float]] {
    print(floatArr)
} else {
    print("failed")
}
```

This produces `[[1.10000002, 2.0], [inf]]` in Swift 3, but fails
in Swift 4.

*To summarize:* Your code is fine.

- If you don't care about "loosing
  precision" or overflows then there is no need to change anything. In Swift 4
  you can write it as `Float(truncating: $0)` to emphasize
  that the result might not be exactly identical to the given
  numbers.
- If you care then you can use the new "exactly" initializers,
  or the bridged cast `as? [[Float]]` in Swift 4.